# Excel: Copy a row to another worksheet if a certain cell is not empty

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, is-empty

i'm looking to use a marco that would be able to search a column in said sheet and if the cell is not empty (cell T), it copy that entire rows data/formatting and paste it into another sheet [sheet "genealogie" in my case] along with any other rows that contained a not empty cell.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISRcD.png

I tried this code but unfortunately it copies all the lines even when the cell in question (column T) is empty.

```
Sub Copyl()
Dim Cell As Range
With Sheets("Tableur")

    For Each Cell In .Range("B7:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Not IsEmpty(Range("T7:T" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row).Value) Then

            .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("genealogie").Rows(Cell.Row)

        End If
    Next Cell

End With
End Sub
```

Thanks by advance....

Comment: `If Not IsEmpty(.Range("T" & Cell.Row)) Then`. Or just use `Range.AutoFilter` and avoid looping.

Comment: `Dim Cell As Range` - `Cell` is a keyword so you might avoid future problems to get in the habit of using a different name

Comment: @JohnnieL - that's a common misconception. `Cells` is a member of the Excel object model. `Cell` is not. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfDlh.png

Comment: yup @bigben - brainfart my end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check the entire range in the T column: just check the single cell in the corresponding row

```
Sub Copyl()
    Dim Cell As Range
    With Sheets("Tableur")

    For Each Cell In .Range("B7:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    '--> check the value in T column in the corresponding row
        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(Cell.Row, "T")) Then

            .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("genealogie").Rows(Cell.Row)

        End If
    Next Cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. identify your input range
2. set an autofilter on that range `Field:=19, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues` (assuming your data starts in Colmun`b`) - the "<>" selects non blanks, the `Operator` parameter is needed to specify the type of filtering operation
3. `input_range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).copy destination_range`
4. `input_range.AutoFilter` to remove autofiltering

Comment: I tried something like this but i got a 400 error....
```

    With ws1 
        lastrow = .Cells(.rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 
        Set rng = .Range("A8:W" & lastrow) 
        .AutoFilterMode = False 
        With rng 
            .AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="<>" 
            On Error Resume Next 
            Set rngToCopy = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 
            On Error GoTo 0 
        End With 
        If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then rngToCopy.Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B8") 
        .AutoFilterMode = False 
    End With 
```